# Support for Refraction/Thickness in Apple Quick Look?

Tags: ios, quicklook, usdz, pbr, usd

I have been testing out models in Apple Quick Look AR on iOS through the USD format, I am finding that Apple Quick Look doesn't appear to support materials that use Refraction/Thickness.

You can see a good example of this issue here with the Mosquito in Amber model that fails to display correctly in the USD format in Apple Quick Look on iOS
https://asset-explorer.needle.tools/MosquitoInAmber

Has anyone else found a way to get Refraction/Thickness using models + materials to work in Apple Quick Look? I realise this stuff may only be supported on visionOS and not iOS AR which is a bit of a gap in the support for materials on Apple platforms.